# Exhaustive filtration of a torsion abelian group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences, filtrations

Let $p$ be a prime integer and $A$ a torsion abelian group. Define a filtration on $A$ by $F_{-1}A=0$ and $F_s A=\ker ( p^{s+1}:A\to A)$ for $s\geq 0$. Why is this filtration exhaustive, i.e. why is $A= \bigcup_s F_sA$.

Comment: Because $A$ being a $p$-torsion abelian group means that for all $x\in A$, there exist $s$ such that $p^{s+1}x=0$.

Comment: Yes, if $A$ is a $p$-torsion abelian group then the statement is clearly true. I suppose this assumption is implicit in the problem statement. Thanks.